# Exclude a line of Code from coverage during Unit Testing with NUnit

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing, nunit

When trying to perform a Unit test on a Unit of code, I am running into an issue, where an Object has not been instantiated (this is a Controller in an API) , and I'm receiving a null reference exception that I cannot bypass to properly test the method. The suspect line is something along:

```
Class.List.Add(Object)
```

where the Class.List is null.

I understand I can write a Null reference check in the controller by doing

```
  if(Class.List != null) 
          {
          Class.List.Add(Object)
          }
```

But I know there must be a cleaner way to do this, that adheres more closely to Unit test best practices.

I am using NUnit with C#.

Thank you for your time and explanations

Edit: To add more context, the Class is  the Program.cs class.

Comment: If you're testing a method that depends on code outside of itself, you could look into mocking. Although I'm not nearly experienced enough with that to even attempt an answer; I've just done it a couple times on methods that were impossible for me to call in a test environment, and this *sounds* similar.

Comment: You should initialize the `List` on class construction. For the NULL check use the [Null Conditiopal Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-): `Class.List?.Add(Object)`.